# Limit number of backgroundworkers to two and complete jobs as they are added

Tags: c#, wpf, queue, backgroundworker

I currently have a treeview whereby the treeView items are bound to an ICommand interface that gets called when item selection is changed as follows:

```
private ICommand _TreeviewSelectedItemChanged;
        public ICommand TreeviewSelectedItemChanged
        {
            get
            {
                if (_TreeviewSelectedItemChanged == null)
                {                    
                    _TreeviewSelectedItemChanged = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                    {
                        foreach (TreeViewClass tree in treeViewObsCollection)
                        {
                            TreeViewSubItem subItem = tree.mainNodes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.treeViewItemIsSelected);
                            if (subItem != null)
                            {
                                queueofJobs.Enqueue(subItem.subItemName);                                
                                //Call Background Worker here?
                            }                            
                        } 
                    });
                }
                return _TreeviewSelectedItemChanged;
            }
        }
```

Every treeView item the user has clicked on will be added to this queue called queueofJobs. What I would like to do is something like this:

1. With the first addition of an item to the queue, a backgroundworker will be automatically started to work on a time-consuming task regarding that item. The challenge I am facing here is that the queue could change depending on the number of items the user has click on, on the treeview items.
2. The backgroundworkers should be limited to at most 2 active at any time cos the operations are read/write dependent and starting too many will have a negative file system performance.
3. The backgroundworkers would perform all the jobs added to the queue (2 jobs at a time) until the queue becomes empty.

I am fine implementing a single backgroundworker but I am currently stuck trying to implement the above scenario whereby the queue of jobs change based on the items the user has selected and 2 backgroundworkers are performing those jobs from the queue until the queue becomes empty.

It would be really great if someone could help me point to a suitable approach to my problem. Any other approach rather than backgroundworker would be fine too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is not the right/best tool for this (anymore). You can use [`TPL Dataflow`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow)'s [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
ActionBlock<TreeViewSubItem> workerBlock = 
    new ActionBlock<TreeViewSubItem>(i => DoWork(i),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 });
```

and then simply call:

```
if (subItem != null)
    workerBlock.Post(subItem);
```

This will work on each sub-item (at max. 2 in parallel) by calling `DoWork` for each item in a separate threadpool-thread.

Comment: Simple, short and sweet. Thanks a lot for your answer :)